# PHP Code Sniffer with Zend Studio Fails

Tags: php, linux, zend-framework2, zend-studio, phpcodesniffer

I'm having an issue with PHP Code Sniffer plugin for Zend studio. I set up my php Executable to be my version of Zend 5.3.14. The PEAR library is also pointed to the executable in my zend directory. When I run code sniffer on a file it creates a new php.ini file in /tmp/zend_debug/session###########/php.ini. I get the following type of error

> PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant T_CALLABLE - assumed 'T_CALLABLE'

If I replace the php.ini in that path with a copy of my current php.ini I can run Code Sniffer in Zend Studio. Anyone have any idea how I can stop this from being generated. Or maybe to change the include path that's being generated?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any knowledge of Code Sniffer or Zend Studio.  But T_CALLABLE did not exist prior to PHP 5.4. I suspect you are running php 5.3 and you plugin assumes php 5.4.